# Installing the GitHub Copilot extension for IntelliJ login failed

Tags: github, intellij-idea, github-copilot

I followed the [steps](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot-in-a-jetbrains-ide) to add the GitHub Copilot extension to the IntelliJ IDEA but ran into an
issue.

Error message:

```
GitHub Copilot

The login to GitHub failed. Reason: Error: EACCES: permission denied, 
open '/Users/MacAir/.config/github-copilot/hosts.json', 
request id: 4, error code: 1001
```

The `.config/github-copilot` folder does not contain a `hosts.json` file. Adding the file did not help.

What can I try now?

Comment: Try to disconnect your github account, connect again. REstart IDE, than connect Copilot.

Comment: Looks like the same question here: https://github.com/community/community/discussions/42761

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by changing the owner of the `.config` folder.
You must run the command in the terminal:

```
sudo chown MacAir /Users/MacAir/.config
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configruation is correct.
According to the error message, there seems to be a problem with file permissions. You need to grant permission to the folder.